# Cambiar url admin de un modelo en Django

Tags: django, django-models

Estoy trabajando en un proyecto de Django y me encuentro que quiero modificar las urls de los modelos que aplica django en el panel de administracion. Básicamente para poder personalizar el menu de administracion.
Este es el codigo donde muestro el menu en el panel de administracion:

```
{% if app_list %}
        {% for app in app_list %}
          <li class="nav-item has-tree-view ">
              <a href="{{ app.app_url }}" class="nav-link">
                  <i class="nav-icon fas fa-object-group"></i> <p>{{ app.name }}</p>
                  <p><i class="right fas fa-angle-left"></i>
                  </p>
              </a>
              {% for model in app.models %}                        
                {% if model.admin_url %}
                <ul class="nav nav-treeview menu-open">
                        <li class="nav-item">
                          <a href="{{ model.admin_url }}" class="nav-link">
                            <i class="nav-icon fas fa-circle"></i> {{ model.name }}
                          </a>
                        </li>
                </ul>
                {% endif %}
              {% endfor %}
            </li>
        {% endfor %}
      {% endif %}
```

El problema es que quiero aplicar un template que tengo creado para cada una de las urls que muestra la variable **{{ model.admin_url }}** pero no se como puedo modificar la url que viene por defecto.

He provado con esto pero no me funciona:

```
def get_urls(self):
    urls = super().get_urls()
    custom_urls = [
        path('/', self.admin_site.admin_view(self.my_view))
    ]

    return custom_urls + urls
```

Alguna ayuda? Gracias